# Как записать в структуру таблицу?

Tags: c, структуры

```
struct EnglishChastota
{
    char Letters[27] = {0};
    float k=0;
};

int main()
{
    struct EnglishChastota Tabliza[2][27] =
{
    'E','T','A','O','I','N','S','H','R','D','L','C','U','M','W','F','G','Y','P','B','V','K','X','J','Q','Z',
    12.7, 9.06, 8.17,7.51,6.97,6.75,6.33,6.09,5.99,4.25,4.03,2.78,2.76,2.41,2.36,2.23,2.02,1.97,1.93,1.49,0.98,0.77,0.15,0.15,0.1,0.05

};
```

Как записать в структуру таблицу , которые я написал в виде HTML'ки  ?
Каким-то таким образом ?

```html
<table class="wikitable">
<tbody><tr>
<th>Буква</th>
<th>E</th>
<th>T</th>
<th>A</th>
<th>O</th>
<th>I</th>
<th>N</th>
<th>S</th>
<th>H</th>
<th>R</th>
<th>D</th>
<th>L</th>
<th>C</th>
<th>U</th>
<th>M</th>
<th>W</th>
<th>F</th>
<th>G</th>
<th>Y</th>
<th>P</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>V</th>
<th>K</th>
<th>X</th>
<th>J</th>
<th>Q</th>
<th>Z
</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>Частота,&#160;%</td>
<td>12,7</td>
<td>9,06</td>
<td>8,17</td>
<td>7,51</td>
<td>6,97</td>
<td>6,75</td>
<td>6,33</td>
<td>6,09</td>
<td>5,99</td>
<td>4,25</td>
<td>4,03</td>
<td>2,78</td>
<td>2,76</td>
<td>2,41</td>
<td>2,36</td>
<td>2,23</td>
<td>2,02</td>
<td>1,97</td>
<td>1,93</td>
<td>1,49</td>
<td>0,98</td>
<td>0,77</td>
<td>0,15</td>
<td>0,15</td>
<td>0,1</td>
<td>0,05
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Таблицу можно в бинарном дереве поиска хранить .

Comment: Лучше немного иначе. `struct e_freq { char c; float k; }; int main () { struct e_freq tab[27] = {{'E', 12.7}, {'T', 9.06}, ... {'Z', 0.05}, {0, 0}}; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам достаточно в структуре хранить `char`, а не массив, массив структур нужен одномерный, раз вы его инициализируете сразу - размер его можно не указывать,  ну и если у вас нет предельно жестких требований к использованию памяти - я бы рекомендовал использовать `double` вместо `float`.

```
struct EnglishChastota
{
    char Letter;
    double k;
};

int main()
{
    struct EnglishChastota Tabliza[] =
    {
        {'E', 12.7}, {'T',9.06}, {'A',8.17},

        ...


        {'Z',0.05}
    }

};
```